# How to build a an event based grid compute engine in microsoft azure?

Tags: azure

I have an application which is written in nodejs hosted in azure. At present, when a user make a rest call, I will perform some calculation by building a grid and send a JSON data of the current state of the grid. Different factors affect the grid, it could be user requests or change in system settings.

I want to modify the current state of the application which evaluates grid only on user requests to constantly running (or sending timed events constantly). I would like anyone interested in a particular event to subscribe to the grid for that event. Based on either user request or timed event or system change event, grid needs to recalculate and then fire any events it might generate. Who ever is interested in the events then act on it.

I did see grid compute in azure website but it looks like it is inactive, no downloads or starred. Could anyone suggest how to approach the problem either in nodejs or C# leveraging azure eco system?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're thinking about **events** and Json and .Net, think [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)

**SignalR** is an WebSockets based event engine that has built-in a ton of fallbacks all the way down to long-polling for those clients that do not support WebSockets to begin with.

With SignalR, you can basically create a "real time" website for your grid compute engine, so that any client connected to it recieves updates in near realtime.